# Stretching LI and contents

Tags: html, css, width

Please consider **[this site](http://www.atasteofnewtown.com/)**.

I'm having trouble stretching the submenu list items in IE7.  Notice that when you hover over one of the LIs under Restaurants, the green doesn't fill the whole line.  I've tried `{width: 100%}`, but that didn't help.

Any ideas why this is OK in Firefox but not IE?  And how to fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:  I can get it to look right if I explicitly specify a width (like 51px), but I definitely don't want to do that in a layout that should be able to support dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that my issue was dropMenuParent had a background color set.  Once I removed that (because it was completely unnecessary), no more black showed up around the green (selected item color).  Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving hasLayout property to the problematic `li`'s or `ul`? Try adding `{ zoom: 1; }` to them.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't help.  However, I noticed in IE Developer Toolbar that hasLayout is still set to -1.

Answer (score -1):

remove padding-left and padding-right from .nav A (includes/styles/styles.css) or make it more precise, or add padding: 0; to your ".nav .dropMenu a" selector.

Comment: If you actually looked at the code, you'd see that it already is in display block style and left/right padding and margins are already at zero. Doesn't seem to help.

Comment: sorry did not notice the link

Comment: I looked the code and edited the answer, there is actually padding in your A. Check it.

Comment: Yes, padding, but not margins.  The background color still spans across the padding.  That wasn't quite it, but I did figure it out.  Thanks.